# laravel sail, can't change files (permission problem)

Tags: laravel, docker

I am using laravel sail and docker-desktop on ubuntu.
Whenever I create a file inside the container I can not change it using VSCode in host.

As I undrestand for files to be editable in both host and container, the ids of users must be same. In my case both users are 1000.

```
host:
hadi:x:1000:1000:Hadi,,,:/home/hadi:/bin/bash

container:
sail:x:1000:1000::/home/sail:/bin/bash
```

Both users are users with IDs of 1000. however, files created on container get id of 100999 on host! This is while I can see that files have sail as their owners in the guest machine.

example:

```
# sail artisan make:model Example
# in the host machine
-rw-r--r-- 1 100999 100999  171  Jul   6 18:00 Example.php
# in the docker
-rw-r--r-- 1 sail sail  171 Jul  6 13:30 Example.php
```

as it can be seen the owner of the file is the sail user, however at the host the owner becomes 100999!
I am using docker-desktop for ubuntu.

and I have modified the docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 pdftk ffmpeg python3 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

# install wkhtmltox_0.12.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget  \
    && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb \
    && apt-get install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb

# config schedules
RUN apt-get -y install cron nano
RUN echo " * * * * * sail cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab

RUN update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

# copy files and set permissions
RUN chown sail:sail -R /var/www
RUN chmod 0775 -R /var/www

COPY ./docker/8.0/start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY ./docker/8.0/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY ./docker/8.0/php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000


ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Comment: Create the file locally, not within the Docker instance. `php artisan` instead of `sail artisan`.

Comment: @ceejayoz that is not really a good solution because when you run `php artisan` it checks for all dependencies and if they are not there it will face an error. the whole point of using containers is having all dependencies contained in the container. So it is not going to mix with other projects with different versions of dependencies or software. In my case I don't want to install Memcache on my host machine.